# Javascript SecurityError

Tags: javascript, security, error-handling, dialog, window

I am using this JS command to openn new dialog window and btw pass parameters to use them in the newly opened window. However I get SecurityError in firebug.

```
var param1= "Internal";
var param2= "Saved";
var url = "http://localhost:8080/player/bin/index.html"
functon callPlayer(){
    newWindow = window.openDialog(url, "Hello", "", param1, param2);
}
```

What could be causing the problem?

Also is it possible somehow with the basic window.open method to send JS parameters that can be used in the new window (or maybe with document.write or innerHTML)?

I use FlashDevelop so it has bin folder with index.html file which is loaded in the new window (index.html loads the swf in it). So basically I want the swf player loaded in the window, but I need parameters from JS which come from database server so that why i want to send params to the new window. (An I must use new window coz I have grid with rows, and every row opens ne window with other parameters)

Comment: What do the variables actually *contain?*

Comment: mostly strings, and maybe number, but I think I will also pass numbers as strings.

Comment: Well, they are very likely the root of the problem so you should really show some examples!

Comment: Okay, now we're nearly there. If you now could post what `url` contains... :)

Comment: Hmm, looks okay! Strange. Do you have any pop-up blockers running?

Comment: Well I tried the window.open method and it works just fine, i.e opens new window as I like, but how to send params to it. Maybe I have to check with pop up blockers. strange

Comment: What error exactly? On which line in the code?

Comment: I dont get any decrp for the error from firebug. It just says Security error. The line where i get error is newWindow = window.openDialog(url, "Hello", "", param1, param2);

Comment: Really odd. Can you try without the parameters and/or a different window name? I don't see how they could be wrong but just to make sure.

Comment: I tried with empty "" params and also for the window params I tried json notation like this {param1:"Internal",param2:"Saved"} and still get the error. Also I added loclhost as an exception for "block pop ups" property in FF. Just to mention in Chrome none of the window.open/openDialog methods work. Are there any issues regarding FF version? I have FF 7 which is latest.

Comment: Just for the cause of this question  I solved the problem like this: I used window.open not window.openDialog and after that line I setup manualiy window parameters like this newWindow.param1="Internal";
    newWindow.param2="saved";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this: I used `window.open` not `window.openDialog` and after that line I setup manualiy window parameters like this:

```
newWindow.param1="Internal";
newWindow.param2="saved";
```

And for the Security error I still get it when using `openDialog`. Not sure why.